# Task always up to date after upgrading from Gradle 1.3 to 1.10

Tags: gradle

My Gradle build uses JavaExec to generate Java source files from an ANTLR grammar. When using Gradle 1.3 it seems to work OK, generating Java when it should and displaying UP-TO-DATE when it should. I upgraded to Gradle 1.10, and now the task always displays UP-TO-DATE, even after a clean (which removes the generated Java files).

My build.gradle contains the following:

```
project.ext.grammarpackage = project.group
project.ext.genAntlrDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources/antlr"

task antlrOutputDir << {
  mkdir(project.ext.genAntlrDir)
}

task generateGrammarSource(dependsOn: antlrOutputDir, type: JavaExec) {
  description = 'Generates Java sources from Antlr4 grammars.'

  def antlrSource = 'src/main/antlr'

  inputs.dir file(antlrSource)
  outputs.dir file(project.ext.genAntlrDir)

  def grammars = fileTree(antlrSource).include('**/*.g4')

  main = 'org.antlr.v4.Tool'
  classpath = configurations.antlr4
  args = ["-visitor", "-o", "${project.ext.genAntlrDir}/${project.ext.grammarpackage}", grammars.files].flatten()
}

compileJava {
  dependsOn generateGrammarSource
  source project.ext.genAntlrDir
}
```

Can anyone see what I should be doing differently? I ran `clean` after upgrading to Gradle 1.10. I know I can make the `generateGrammarSource` task run with the `--rerun-tasks` option, but don't want to force it to run all the time, just when it's not up to date.

Comment: Hard to say from a distance. Are you sure the task produces correct outputs in the first place? Also try to delete (or rename) `~/.gradle` and `$projectDir/.gradle`. PS: `project.` can be omitted in a build script. More importantly, `ext.` should only be used when defining an extra property, but not afterwards. Instead of `project.ext.genAntlrDir`, `genAntlrDir` or `project.genAntlrDir` should be used.

Comment: The task `antlrOutputDir` shouldn't be needed, as output directories (as declared in `generateGrammarSource`) are created automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! Removing the `$projectDir/.gradle` file and allowing Gradle to recreate it did the trick. I'll also make the other changes you suggested. If you copy your comment to an answer, I will accept it.